# Sharing Wifi connection over ethernet, Still no internet access

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, sharing

I am trying to share my laptops (16.04) wifi connection with a beagle bone (14.04 no gui) through ethernet. I've done this process before on a raspberry pi and an odroid-xu4 but the same process does not seem to be working for the beagle bone.

ping www.google.com 
hangs for awhile until finally saying unknown host

sudo apt-get update hangs on 0% connecting to ports.ubuntu.com until eventually having many failed connections and errors.

Here is my network settings on my laptop:

[image]

And here are the settings for my beagle bone:

[image]

Those are all the settings that I can think of that are relevant (ifconfigs are posted below because I don't have rep to post more than 2 links...)

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LYqNq.png) Laptop ifconfig
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oJvft.png) beagle bone ifconfig

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Comment: will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed my problem.
I added

nameserver 10.42.0.1

to my resolv.conf file on the beagle bone and can now ping and run apt-get update.